# How to use str.replace with many find/replace pairs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, find-replace

I need a function in JavaScript that takes one string as input, replaces many substrings with their corresponding values, then returns the result. For example:

```js
function findreplace(inputStr) {
    const values = {"a": "A",
              "B": "x",
              "c": "C"};

    // In this example, if inputStr is "abc", then outputStr should be "AbC".

    return outputStr
}
```

I know how to individually find and replace, but I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this with many pairs of (case-sensitive) values at once.

Thank you!

Comment: Are keys always a single character or also substrings?

Comment: For now, they will always be single characters, though that may change in the future. It is preferable that the solution works with any substrings, but it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over `values` with the help of `Object.entries(values)`:

```js
function findreplace(inputStr) {
  const values = {
    "a": "A",
    "B": "x",
    "c": "C"
  };
  for (const [search, replace] of Object.entries(values)) {
    inputStr = inputStr.replace(search, replace);    
  }
  return inputStr;
}

console.log(findreplace("abc"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `join keys` to build a regex and then `replace` accordingly

```js
function findreplace(inputStr) {
  let values = { "a": "A", "B": "x", "c": "C" };
  let regex = new RegExp("\\b" + Object.keys(values).join('|') + "\\b", 'g')
  return inputStr.replace(regex, (m) => values[m] )
}

console.log(findreplace('aBc'))
console.log(findreplace('AbC'))
console.log(findreplace('ABC'))
```